# Android UI Best Practice For iOS UIButton TypeInfoLight

Tags: android

Is there an Android best practice for providing help text about a particular button or function on an app screen?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't apply in general, but remember to always provide title attribute to your ActionBar action items. Long press on those buttons will show toast with the title.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the `android:contentDescription` attribute in the XML?

There's also a nice article about this on the [developer.android.com site](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/index.html)

Comment: I'm looking for something similar that iOS exposes, the UIButton TypeInfoLight.  The "i" icon..